# SQL Return latest occurrence

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to return the latest occurrence of a value for each FromID in a table.
Lets say we have the following table:

```
FromID   |  ToID  |   Description
  12         11            Apple
  12         11            Pear
  53         83            Tomato
  33         54            Banana
  33         54            Grape
  46         67            Berry
```

My Output should be:

```
FromID   |  ToID  |   Description
  12         11            Pear
  53         83            Tomato
  33         54            Grape
  46         67            Berry
```

Im using the following code to get my entities:

```
$options = array(
'type' => 'object',
'subtype' => 'file',   
'joins' => '',
'wheres' => '',
),

$files = elgg_get_entities_from_metadata($options);
```

How would this be accomplished?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using Mysql

Comment: Is your source data ordered in some way?

Comment: Does a fromid always have the same toid?

Comment: At present, the problem is insoluble. Rows in an RDBMS table have no order. Once you figure out how to address that issue,  see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You should probably make each row timestampable.  Or introduce a primary key on the table and, you can still build a composite index between FromID and ToID if you need.

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
SELECT FromID, ToID, MAX(Description)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY FromID, ToID
```